# Webpack can't resolve vue in node_modules/vue-template-compiler

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I have a simple Typescript project with this code:

```
import {
  parseComponent,
  compile as compileTemplate,
  ASTElement,
} from "vue-template-compiler";
...
```

I compile it using `tsc` with:

```
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "commonjs",
```

And it gives code like this:

```
const vue_template_compiler_1 = require("vue-template-compiler");
```

In my `package.json` I have this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
```

But I *don't* have `"vue"`, because I don't need all of Vue - just the template compiler.

This all works fine, but I'm trying to use Webpack to bundle everyone into a single file. However, when I run webpack I get this error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/vue-template-compiler/index.js 2:19-41
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue' in '/path/to/myproject/node_modules/vue-template-compiler'
 @ ./build/analysis.js 8:32-64
 @ ./build/index.js 8:19-40
```

This corresponds to the `require("vue-template-checker")` line. Why do I get this error?

Here's my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  target: "node",
  entry: "./build/index.js",
  mode: "production",
  output: {
    filename: "index.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.BannerPlugin({ banner: "#!/usr/bin/env node", raw: true }),
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That module makes Vue version check during import. I guess, you want to skip that check. I would try [aliasing](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only). Something like:

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue-template-compiler$': 'vue-template-compiler/build.js'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! Where does it do the version check?

Comment: @Timmmm In package.json entryfile - index.js